# App doesn't run on simulators or archive, devices work

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, android-studio, app-store-connect

App doesn't run on IOS simulators or building archive but runs on devices.
It used to run fine, suddenly (can't pinpoint what is currently different that could cause this) a similar issue happened on android with the File name is too long error after multiple flutter cleans, removing all caches it worked on a real device then on the simulators again, doesn't work for IOS though.

Error message

```
/Users/yassin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dnjtfjbcotehrpgzrmybaaeugzpl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Runner.app: File name too long Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Unhandled error domain NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code 63
```

More details on the error when running from xcode for a simulator:

```
Failure Reason: Unhandled error domain NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code 63 User Info: { FunctionName = IXCopyItemAtURL; IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher; SourceFileLine = 121; }
```

One weird behaviour i've noticed is that dart analysis is taking so long to launch, and when running on a device it builds in normal time but takes so long to install (4+ minutes) On a Macbook M1, on both android and ios which is something unusual.

Flutter doctor

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-arm, locale
en-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.61.0)
```

Things i have tried:

1. Flutter clean + Flutter pub get
2. Deleting xcodes derived data folder + Restarting laptop and xcode
3. flutter pub cache repair
4. Pod install, update
5. Revoking all certificates, installing new ones
6. Closing automatic signing, downloading profile
7. Locking & unlocking Keychain login access.

Flutter run --verbose error logs:

```
An error was encountered processing the command
(domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=63):
                    copyfile of
                    file:///Users/yassin/Desktop/Projects/handles/build/ios/ipho
                    nesimulator/Runner.app/ to
                    file:///Users/yassin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
                    /B864AB8C-79BE-4A09-9351-DDCA31E8C22F/data/Containers/Shared
                    /SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.installcoordinationd/Libr
                    ary/InstallCoordination/PromiseStaging/C21EB07A-E655-4BBA-8B
                    07-5DA8B5397AE4/Runner.app failed: File name too long
                    Unhandled error domain NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code 63
[  +15 ms] Unable to install

/Users/yassin/Desktop/Projects/handles/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app on
           B864AB8C-79BE-4A09-9351-DDCA31E8C22F. This is sometimes caused by a
malformed
           plist file:
           ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
           An error was encountered processing the command
(domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain,
           code=63):
           copyfile of

file:///Users/yassin/Desktop/Projects/handles/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.a
           pp/ to

file:///Users/yassin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B864AB8C-79BE-4A09-

9351-DDCA31E8C22F/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.insta

llcoordinationd/Library/InstallCoordination/PromiseStaging/C21EB07A-E655-4BBA-8B
           07-5DA8B5397AE4/Runner.app failed: File name too long
           Unhandled error domain NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code 63
             Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl install
             B864AB8C-79BE-4A09-9351-DDCA31E8C22F

/Users/yassin/Desktop/Projects/handles/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app
[   +7 ms] Error launching application on iPhone 12.
[  +10 ms] "flutter run" took 445,079ms.
[  +14 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand
           (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:669:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1125:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      CommandRunner.runCommand
(package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me after many days was **deleting all hidden files** in the project folder besides git related ones, .idea, .packages etc.. As well as podspec.lock and the **Build folder manually**.

What worked for someone else with the same issue was "Removing the flutter installation folder, then fetching again from the repo"

Both options should hopefully solve your issue.